# Horizontal recyclerview with current item scaled and next item displayed a bit

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to make a horizontal recyclerview like the one in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMHeE.jpg), the screenshot on the left

I managed to do the horizontal part, but the next and previews cards are not being displayed.

here's the xml recyclerview

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_cards"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:requiresFadingEdge="horizontal"
    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:listitem="@layout/recyclerview_card_row" />
```

Here's the recyclerview_card_row.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_qicard_accent"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/qicard_card"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layoutDirection="ltr"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_card_number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="* * * *  * * * *  * * * *  6968"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and here's the activity code for the recyclerview

```
    rv_cards = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_cards);
    rv_cards.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rv_cards.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));

    SnapHelper snapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper();
    snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(rv_cards);
```